# Android app working in phones but not in tablets

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, tablet

I've developed an android app for my final project at college.
While I was developing I used a physical device for testing, an android phone 4.4 kitkat.
I also used several **smartphone** emulators to test my UI with different android versions and It all worked fine.
The problem appears when I tried to run the app on a **tablet**, It throws a java null pointer exception pointing at the button listener (setOnClickListener()). 
(All this buttons belong to a fragment) 
It also have problems when I run a **tablet emulator**.
I didn't post any code here because the null pointer exception belongs to the first listener that I declare, and maybe It has something to do with the device.
To resume what is mention above, if it's a tablet It won't work (even an emulator, null pointer exception is thrown). If it's a phone It will work.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Crash only occur in Table and never in Phone mean there is a chance that Tablet UI is not the same as Phone UI. Please check the layout folder under res. Also please put up project directory structure if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. So I guess you've different layouts for tab and phone. You need to post your layouts in this case.

I had a similar problem once, so I'm just guessing that, your tab layout has a Button (which is creating null pointer exception) `android:onClick="onClick"` attribute in its declaration. If you implicitly implement a `setOnClickListener` for this `Button` in your activity its not necessary to set `onClick` attribute. If your activity doesn't have an `onClick` function, where your Button is referring to an `onClick` function, it'll get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I've checked my layouts and I have some button fields with incorrect Ids in the /layout-large-port directory, that's why I was getting the null pointer exception.
I'll clarify this a little bit:
My application is intended to work only in portrait mode on smartphones and tablets, so I created an additional folder called /layout-large-port.
So far I have this structure /layout(for smartphones) /layout-large-port(for tablets > 7'') with the layouts inside.

Next time I'll check it in more detail. Thanks for your time guys!